# C/C++ definitions of functions

Tags: c++, c, printf, declaration

Yesterday, I have been watching discussion here, about compilers and linkers. It was about C library function definitions. I have never thought of that, so it inspired me to do some searching, but I cannot find exactly what I want. I wonder, what is the smallest syntax you need to add into your source code to enable just printf() function. I mean the function declaration from stdio.h you need.

Comment: Why do you want this?  What benefit does shortest give you?  For *printf* in particular, your library might be (slightly) more verbose to mark the function as one that needs format-specifiers checked (e.g. gcc does this with `-Wformat` enabled).  Telling us why you don't want to include <stdio.h> could allow us to provide a better solution.

Comment: It is simple, I just want to better understand the way from printf() to actual code. Is there any good articles on web? Becouse many books are not availaible in my country.

Comment: Do you want to write your own function, let's call it `my_printf`, which behaves identically as the standard `printf`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. I dont need it to be as complex as printf(), just to print to stdout simple string.

Answer (score 3):

The C99 declaration of `printf()` is

```
int printf(const char *restrict, ...);
```

but most compilers will also accept

```
int printf(const char *, ...);
```

See also C99 section 7.1.4, §2:

> Provided that a library function can be declared without reference to any type defined in a
>   header, it is also permissible to declare the function and use it without including its
>   associated header.

*Note:* In this case, the `restrict` qualifier combined with `const` promises the compiler that the format string is never modified within `printf()`, even if the pointer is passed again as one of the variadic arguments.

Comment: @David: `restrict` is not the argument name, but one of the three C99 type qualifiers (the others are `const` and `volatile`)

Comment: @Christoph: Actually, `restrict` means the compiler can ignore aliasing and you *cannot* pass the format string again as a variadic argument.  If you do pass it twice, that's undefined behavior; see 6.7.3.1/4 in the C standard.

Comment: @Roger: I thought so too (check my edits on the answer), but that's wrong: 6.7.3.1, example 3 explicitly shows that two `restrict` arguments may alias each other as long as the pointed-to object isn't modified within the function, which `printf()` doesn't do, ie `printf(foo, foo)` should be legal!; you can't see from the declaration alone whether it's legal to pass in aliased pointers

Comment: @Christoph: I actually deciphered (or thought I did) /4 to double check before posting, but then you had to go and ruin it with a mere *example*.

Comment: @Roger: the reason for this somewhat confusing definition is that `restrict` isn't there to make promises to the _caller_ (as a `const` would do), but to allow further optimizations within the _callee_ ; only when you combine these qualifiers (ie `const *restrict`) you're able to deduce further information from the declaration alone

Answer (score 1):

The definition is usually compiled in a shared library. The declaration is what you need. Not having a declaration in scope invokes undefined behavior. So, for every library, you'd typically have a (set of) header file(s) and the compiled binary shared/static library. You compile your sources by including appropriate headers and link with the library. To bring in the declaration in scope use the `#include` directive. E.g. for `printf` you'd do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But then any decent book on C or C++ should already cover this in detail and with better examples.

Comment: Is there a way to see actual definitions of these functions? In C or ASM code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler and platform.

On most cases just declaring

```
int printf(const char *, ...);
```

will just do, however, your particular compiler/platform or C library implementation even can change this declaration, for calling convention purposes.

All in all it is not worth it to try and declare things yourself, as this could be a violation of the one definition rule. You should always include the apropriate header, stdio.h(cstdio for C++) in this case.